# Will robocopy resume after being aborted?

Tags: robocopy

My *users* directory is 58 GB in size and I am copying it to a portable USB backup drive from Windows recovery using [Robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy).

```
robocopy G:\Users\ E:\Backup\T420\ /MIR /SEC /MT:32 /V /LOG:G:\bak\robocopy.txt
```

The laptop is USB 2 and the backup drive is USB 3.

It has been running for over 18 hours now which is longer than my expectation.

Even at a speed slow for USB 2 it should only take about 8 hours

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=58+gB+at+2+MB%2Fs

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and inspect the log to see what is going on then run the command again will it take the same amount of time or will it resume from where it left off?

Assuming it resumes, what sort of time overhead is there to work out which files are left to copy and where to resume from?

**EDIT**: It turns out that the reason it was taking so long was because of some fake/not-fully-sync'd OneDrive files that couldn't be copied and [default values of retrying 1 million times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708130/why-does-robocopy-retries-1000000-times). Changing the retry and wait allowed it to complete `/r:2 /w:5`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103011/discussion-on-question-by-opticyclic-is-it-ok-to-stop-robocopy).

Comment: You're not really asking "is it OK to stop robocopy", but "will robocopy resume after being aborted". I suggest modifying the title to that effect

Comment: At first, I read it as "is it OK to stop Robocop?"

Answer (score 66):

If the folder contains a very large number of files, then it will indeed take
a long time, required by the frequent accesses to the disk catalogs,
for both source and target.

In addition, a USB3 disk on a USB2 port will work at the speed of USB2.
The USB3 disk will adapt itself to the port and its protocol when doing
the initial handshake.

You are using `/MT:32` for Multi-Threaded, so telling robocopy to copy
32 files at once. This will cause 32 threads to fight for access to the
disks, and will slow the copy even further, with the disk's head wasting time by
going back and forth over the disk. In the case of slow USB2 copy,
Multi-Threaded is not recommended.

Use Restartable mode `/Z` to process partially-copied files.
With this option, when the copy is interrupted so some particular file is
partially copied, the next execution of robocopy can pick up where it left off
rather than re-copying the entire file. There are unfortunately cases where
this switch will slow down the copy.

Comment: Sometimes it really sucks that I can only upvote an answer. This is not a good answer, its a great answer! :) +10 in my opinion. :D

Comment: Its a useful answer and has several great tips. However, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: ??? The answer says how to restart robocopy in an efficient manner. It also explains why it was so slow and how to speed it up. A complete fix of all your problems isn't an answer?

Comment: Will multithreading really slow things down? I'd have thought the bottleneck was the USB2 connection, not the disk.

Comment: @HongOoi: When copying 32 files which are in different places on the disk, if each of the 32 threads gets to copy one block/sector in turn, the head of the disk will need to position itself to the 32 positions on each write. Head movements are physical and so are very slow. In contrast, while copying one file in a sequential manner, the head just keeps writing the whole track at the speed of rotation (if the data transfer from the computer is coming fast enough).

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't USB2 (10Mbps max IIRC) still be slower?

Comment: @HongOoi: Depends on the quality of the disk. Many have some cache memory that allows writing one track at a go.

Comment: @Hong Ooi, USB2 is 480Mbps. And yes, too many simultaneous transfers (threads) can definitely slow things down, especially with rotating disks but even with SSDs. You might want to experiment with a lower number (the default number of threads when using the /MT option is 8 AFAIK).

Comment: @StarCat Thanks, I was thinking of USB 1.1

Comment: Using multiple threads does not necessarily cause more head movements. In fact, depending on the quality of the operating system's IO scheduler, it might actually reduce head movements. Because the application sends multiple IO requests in parallel, the OS has a better idea of what the application is doing, and can reorder IO requests to minimize head movements. As an analogy, consider an elevator servicing multiple people simultaneously compared to serving only one at a time. In fact, the [elevator algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_algorithm) is a well known IO scheduler type.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: An elevator can carry multiple persons, but a disk head can only serve one request. It's not the subject here, as there are many optimizations for a disk scheduler to improve (but not resolve) the performance in this case.

Comment: @LPChip bounties are what you're looking for ;)

Comment: @harrymc you missed the analogy. Yes, an elevator can carry many people, which is equivalent to many requests in the queue. The elevator is only on one floor at a time, which is equivalent to the disk head being on a given track. You get *more* throughput by having several outstanding requests and letting the scheduler service them in the fastest order, than by taking them strictly sequentially (an elevator with a 1-person capacity).

Comment: @hobbs, this would be true if it wasn't just Robocopy accessing the disk.  With just Robocopy accessing it, single-threaded mode is fastest, as you get zero requests for anything *but* the current floor, which requires no head movement.  All but the simplest schedulers have some sort of latency-based criteria built in, such that an outstanding request will be serviced in a reasonable amount of time, even if doing so will reduce overall throughput.

Comment: @Mark not arguing with that — it's true, but so is what G. Sliepen said. :)

Comment: @harrymc "Is it OK to stop Robocopy?" is what you didn't answer.

Comment: Hate to break it to you guys .. but 480mb/s is the theoretical port-limit .. then comes the actual USB2 File transfer protocol .. which has a serious flaw .. and allows a single transfer of about 25 to 30 MB /S (far from those 60 MB theoretical value) - now if you have a second USB drive sharing the same BUS .. and copy a second file .. the overall transfer rate grows to about 35MB /s . a third come close the 40 . then they start to interfere and it wont get any faster ... if you can, invest in a USB 3 card for your computer if possible

Comment: @G.Sliepen This is all hypothetical and in reality the OS doesn't know what any of the threads are actually doing and will not attempt to reorder them.

Answer (score 27):

It **is** OK to stop Robocopy in the middle of an operation.

[By default](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) it will not re-copy the files that have already been copied.

The overhead for determining where to resume from (or essentially to check which files are the same) is very low - only seconds.

However, if you are not writing to a log (or are using `/TEE` to also write to a console) the `/V` will increase this overhead as it will take longer to write all the lines to the console.

**NB**: Restartable mode (as mentioned in the comments) is just for restarting individual files (e.g. if a giant file is stopped in the middle you can resume part way through instead of copying the whole file again) and is not *required* for resuming batch copying as asked in the question.

Comment: I don't see anything in your link saying it's okay to stop Robocopy in the middle of an operation. Particularly, it sounds like you can easily end up with corrupt, half-copied files if you try to interrupt and resume a Robocopy operation without using restartable mode.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica robocopy leaves the file with a really old modified date until the complete file is copied. Robocopy will, by default, recopy partially copied files. One of the great things about robocopy is the ability to stop and restart multiple times and never lose where you left off. Restartable mode will help copy large files over shoddy connections.

Answer (score 22):

I've used `robocopy` for years now, and know that you can stop a copy in the middle of a file and restarting will swiftly get back to where it left off.  Unless you use the `/XN` option, `robocopy` will delete whatever the last file it was working on and start the copy again.  When it first creates a file, it sets the "Modified" time to 1/1/1980, so basically as long as your clock is set correctly, it will see that time and restart the copy process.  As you've stated, other files will be ignored since they have the same modified date/time as the source files.

Personally, I always use the `/TEE` option along with the `/V` and `/LOG:` options when using `robocopy` so that I can monitor what is going on, (and if a crash happens, I can go back and see if there were issues as well).  It will slow things down a little bit if you have an extreme amount of small files (tens of thousands or more), but it can also help you determine if there's a problem.  If you shrink the height, or better yet, minimize the command prompt window, you can greatly speed up the copy when you have a bunch of small files.

18 hours is very long for the amount you're trying to copy, so it's possible that you either have an insane amount of small files that you're trying to copy, or you have some recursion in your directory structure.  Since you have a log, you could try looking at the bottom of it and see if the directory structure is repeating itself.  If it is, you could try skipping junction points with `/XJD` to see if that allows you to stop the loop(s) it's getting stuck in.  The `/XD` option can also be used to completely ignore specific directories.

About the `/Z` option, this option ONLY works for "network transfers".  I put that in quotes because local copies will NOT use the restartable mode; however if `robocopy` sees a network path, it will use restartable mode, even if the source and destination are local, (this could just be my version of `robocopy` since I'm not moving past Windows 7).  If you share out your drive or a folder on the drive, (preferably to an account that only you have access to), and enable the `Change` permission(s), then use that path as the destination, it should work in restartable mode.  Granted, there may be a hit in performance when using restartable mode.

Comment: Excellent advice on `/XJD`. I’m not sure how to robocopy handles the situation, but if the OP is copying the user profile folder, the appdata folder classically has a endless loop that always causes problems with recursion.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it OK to stop Robocopy?

I kill the Robocopy task often without a problem. If the process is killed, the file that was being copied will, as far as I remember, have (a) time stamp of 1980-01-01 (b) size same as the original file.

> Assuming it resumes, what sort of time overhead is there to work out
>   which files are left to copy and where to resume from?

If you start the task again with those parameters, it will (a) skip the files that it copied already (b) re-copy the file that was interrupted because of date mismatch (c) copy the files that it did not in previous attempt (d) delete the files from destination that no longer exist in source because of `/MIR` switch.

> It turns out that the reason it was taking so long was because...

Before killing the process, you can open the log file in a text editor to see what it is doing; the last line will contain the file it is copying and its size. If there was an error, that too will be listed such as:

> 2019/12/13 06:26:38 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying File C:\Redacted
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.
>
> Waiting 60 seconds... Retrying...

Once the copy is successful, the log file will contain a summary that includes the transfer rate (megabytes per minute) that will give you a rough idea of how much time it'll take next time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to [premise-challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t) a bit here. I understand the frustration of a slow copy, but interrupting the copy is not how you check copy progress.

### Look at the disk I/O history chart

Fire up Performance Monitor and look at disk I/O activity history.  You should do this with the system quiescent; if it's doing a lot of other stuff you could be looking at *that* disk activity.  However, that will be spiky; you're looking for the "baseline" activity that is there all the way across the chart.  Mine on the Mac splits it into reads and writes; obviously you're looking at writes. (most other activity will be reads).

[image]

*Older Mac version. Windows' is more robust.  The first lump is rsync planning the copy, the second lump is three fat MP4 video files, and the last lump is a bazillion little files.*

In my experience, In practice, this bar will jump up and down quite a bit.  When copying large single files - videos and TIFF files, it pegs at whatever the hardware maximum throughput is.*

But when copying bazillions of little files, MBps throughput tanks ... because the drives must read (and write) a directory entry for each file.  You don't have head seek times and wait-for-sector-to-come-around delays on Flash memory keyfobs, *but you do on physical hard drives - bigtime*. Hard drives and robust OS's have some strategies to ease the pain, but there's still big pain.

- This is why I turn all my collections of little files into ZIP packages, tarballs, or disk images.

### Look at the files themselves arriving on the destination drive

Use your windows (or a command prompt) to browse the destination directories. Find the "leading edge" of the copy, i.e. the directories being added into right now.  Watch the activity and see if it's normal.

### Listen to the hard drive

If your drive is going

> tick... tick... tick...

That's a copy going well. The drive is doing big block transfers, using its formatted sector arrangement to best advantage, etc.   If on the other hand you here

> shikkita shikkita shikkita

That's disk thrash. Something has gone wrong with your backup, and it's killing throughput. That sound means the drive is seeking the head *a lot* - and **when the head's moving, it's not copying**. Worse, when it arrives, it must stabilize and then wait an average of 0.5 disk platter revolutions for the desired sector to come around.  Drives spin at 5400-10,000 RPM, so that's 3-6 ms every seek.

In the earlier diagram, indeed, the fat section had the drive quiet as a mouse, and in the later section, shickkita.

> For instance, once I had a nest of 5.5 million tiny (30-500 byte) files in the middle of a big backup.  When the drive started sounding like a World War I melee, I checked the graph and saw the bad news.  At that rate, the copy would've taken days.
>
> So I quit apps, created an ample RAMdisk, and copied the 5.5M files to the RAMdisk.  Reading from HDD, this benefited from disk cache; writing was instant of course. **This took a half hour**.  Then I wrote it back to hard drive as a ZIP file, which wrote as one continuous data stream, so  "tick...tick...tick...". That was even faster.
>
> Deleting the 5.5M files took an age, but then, the ZIP file backed up in less than a minute.  *Big improvement over a day!*

**As far as when to interrupt the copy, you do that when the above is telling you the copy is not working properly, and you have a plan or want to experiment to fix it.**

### Never, ever, ever multi-thread

The meters show you'll get best throughput when streaming a single large file like a video.  The drive's sector optimization is working at peak performance: the next needed sector appears under the disk head just as it's needed.

But suppose you copy 2 large videos at the same time.  **The disk is trying to do both at once**: It seeks to video 1, writes a block, seeks to video 2, writes a block, seeks to video 1, writes a block, ad nauseum. Suddenly we're seeking instead of writing, and throughput does the obvious thing.

So don't do that. And the disk I/O history chart will tell you why.

> For instance I "rsync" from internal HDD to External 2.  I also rsync from External 1 to External 2.  These are all set up in scripts.  I don't run both at once, because they'll fight over External 2, and it'll slow both copies down.

Now what you did, with `/MT:32`, is tell it to thread **32 copies at once**, which is the very thing I'm here telling you not to do.  *Maybe multi-threading helps on hybrid, RAM disks, RAIDs, or good elevator-seeking algorithms that play nice with the particular data-set. That doesn't sound like it's here.  But regardless, *don't take my word on it* -- you should be using the graphs to experiment and find the happy number for *your* hardware.  (Which I fully expect will be "1").

---

* lowest of a) computer USB, b) device USB, c) read drive throughput and d) write drive throughput.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer addresses:**

> It has been running for over 18 hours now which is longer than my expectation.
>   Even at a speed slow for USB 2 it should only take about 8 hours

and suggests a possible alternative to Robocopy

---

**TRANSFER SPEED CHECKING:**

Others have addressed possible reasons for lower than expected speed.

**CURRENT SPEED:**

Noting the rate of change of the free space on the target drive will tell you the current copying rate.  While doing this with say 10 seconds between checks, giving it say a minute will give you a better average.

You can do this with whatever Windows tool suits or, by using my preferred option, of using what nowadays passes as a "DOS Window".

```
       dir target:\
```

should be adequate.

**TRANSFER SPEED TO DATE:**

You can find how many files and what data volume have been copied so far with eg

```
     dir target:\destination_folder /s
```

This will slow the copying rate during the dir process.
Subsequent DIRs will usually be faster due to caching of the majority of the result.

---

**TRANSFER SPEED ADEQUACY:**

58 GB/18 hours is somewhat under 1 MB/second, which is low for any USB2 - USB3 copying process.  The size of the actual files transferred can be accessed as above - allowing you to tell if the rate is even far slower than 1 MB/s.

Worst case transfer speeds that I have experienced on a modern machine (OK i7) have been in the 501- MB/s

**Possible (only) helps:**

I am not familiar with Robocopy.
I use a very old (2001) version of XXCOPY for similar purposes as it works well and the licence terms suit my needs. XXCOPY has a flag "/nX0" which disables the short-name-preservation feature in some cases. In some situations this very greatly speeds up transfer rate. Some similar setting  in Robocopy may help.

I also assign source and destination paths to dummy drive letters using Ye Olde DOS Subst command

```
        eg subst a: pathname
```

This allows copy of some files which otherwise fail to copy - including those with extremely (stupidly) long file names.

**============================**

*Possible interest.*
The question related to the use of Robocopy.
The following script uses XXCOPY to perform a similar task.
Existing files are not recopied.
Y: and Z: are used in place of direct source and destination parameters to eliminate certain copying errors (filename tooooooooo long).
I'm uncertain why this works, but it does.

```
    subst y: /D ; release mapped drive
    subst y: Src_Drive:\source_path

    subst z: /D ; release mapped drive
    subst z: Dest_Drive:\destination_path

    **xxcopy /bb /s /h /nx0 y:\*.*  z:\**

rem /bb - if not exist
rem /s  - all subdirs
rem /h  - incl hidden files
rem nx0 - don't preserve short file name
```